# UIAppearance overwrites custom textColor on UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, interface-builder, uiappearance, ibdesignable

I setup UILabel appearance in my app delegate using:

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.white
```

I also have a custom UIView subclass that contains a UILabel along with some other elements (omitted here):

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {
    private let descriptionLabel = HCLabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.descriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        // ... other things not related to descriptionLabel
    }
}
```

If I instantiate `CustomView` in a storyboard, everything works just fine. If, however, I instantiate it in code, the descriptionLabel is white (appearance color), not black (the color I set). What's going on here? The way I understood it was that if I set a custom color, the appearance color will not be used.

Comment: Have you verified that `setup` is actually called?

Comment: yes it is called and the color of UILabel is changed, but apparently gets changed back somewhere later

Comment: I edited the question to fix an error - `CustomView` is not instantiated using a storyboard, but programmatically.

Comment: Implement `didMoveToSuperview` and call setup there.

Comment: This does indeed work, but can you explain why? I know UIAppearance properties are set when a view moves to superview/window, but I was also under the impression that setting a custom value would prevent this. I don't think if another dev on the project will use UILabel in a similar way 6 months from now, he/she will ever be able to figure out why setting textColor simply has no effect...

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious, but maybe that's just me. I gave more detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're experiencing is simply a matter of the exact timing with which the UIAppearance proxy applies its settings to a new UIView. When are we to suppose it does this? It can't possibly do it *before* `init`, because `init` is the first thing that happens in the life of the UIView. Thus, the order of events is like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup() // black
}
// and some time later, UIAppearance proxy comes along and sets it to white
```

So your goal is to call `setup` pretty early in the life of the label — and certainly before the user ever has a chance to see it — but not *so* early that the UIAppearance proxy acts *later*. Let's move the call to `setup` to a bit later in the life of the label:

```
// some time earlier, UIAppearance proxy sets it to white
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    setup() // black
}
```

Now we're acting *after* the appearance proxy has had a chance to act, and so your settings are the last to operate, and they win the day.

We remain in ignorance of *how* early we could move the call to `setup` and still come along *after* the appearance proxy setting has been obeyed. If you have time, you might like to experiment with that. For example, `willMoveToSuperview` is earlier; if you call `setup` there (and not in `didMoveToSuperview`), does that work? Play around and find out!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still think I don't quite understand how UIAppearance is supposed to be used, though - if using it means I can't customize UILabel's anymore in interface builder, and in code only by jumping through hoops every time I use it, this seems like a pretty flawed design to me. I guess I will not be able to use this then. Still, your answer works and is well-explained, so I will accept it ;-)